# Could something be done to prevent correcting British English to American English?

Tags: feature-request

As far as I can see, the problem of changing British English to American English and vice versa is continuously happening. Some people don't care at all, others feel slightly irritated and some even become enraged. Could something be done to fix this issue?

For example, an option to flag the post with "This is American/British English post" would be great.

Comment: Are you familiar with this question: [Standardization of English, etc.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3224/8610)?

Comment: A lot of the edits I see along these lines are done out of benevolent ignorance, the editor being wholly unaware another way of writing a word was valid and not a typo.  A notice about a particular form of English being used won't do much if the person has trouble distinguishing regular spelling from typos — these "corrections" will still happen.

Answer (score 7):

Trouble with such a flag (apart from the SE staff developers are super-never going to entertain such an idea) is that BrE and AmE aren't the only correct English spelling standards, and even within those two, there are acceptable less-well-known spelling variants.

[The solution](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/321) is generally to use the existing tools: re-editing to honour the original spelling, comments to settle confusions, and a heaping helping of respect and patience for each other.

It won't make the “incorrections” ever end, but it will make the process of holding back the tide of hypercorrection more pleasant and sustainable.

Comment: Haha! "Incorrections", that's a good word for it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is important enough to require that someone programs a flag, and I don't think the flag would add anything to what our site is for. At most, it will generate some edits and, hopefully, some edit reasons like "it was British English, not a misspelling".