# Question editing rules and etiquette

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

If someone has edited another person's question in a way that, although perhaps beneficial overall, also introduces grammatical, spelling, or other errors, is it considered appropriate form to edit the question to fix those errors?

And if so, what is the appropriate course of action when the change to fix those errors is below the minimum threshold for an edit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, please fix those errors. It's appropriate form to fix errors in posts regardless of how they got there.

Be mindful that sometimes spelling differences are regional English variations (e.g. USA's color vs Australia's colour), see [Standardization of English, etc.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/1204)

If the edit is below the threshold you've got some options:

1. Hunt around to see if there's something else that can be improved in the same edit. There's *probably* something.
2. Leave a comment: “@user12345 There is a typo in 'Figter' but I can't suggest an edit.” You can ping people who edited the post even if they don't show up in the ping autocomplete. (I promise.) Up to you whether you ping the OP or the person who edited it.
3. Drop into [RPG General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) and ask someone for assistance to make the edit for you.

Thank you for your effort and keen eye.

Comment: 4. Trust that another user with unrestricted edit privileges will notice and take care of it. Typos in questions rarely last long around here.